# How to package an application in a docker image capable of running on a Spark cluster in Kubernetes?

Tags: docker, apache-spark, kubernetes

I am new to running Spark on Kubernetes and I have a very simple app I am trying to package to run in the Spark on K8s cluster that I have setup. The challenge I am facing is how to package my app to run in Spark? I installed Spark on K8's from the [Spark Operator](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spark-on-k8s-operator) and I notice that the examples use the image `gcr.io/spark-operator/spark:v3.0.0`.

I noticed the Spark [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-kubernetes.html#docker-images) mentions this `docker-image-tool.sh` script to generate an app. but this looks like it would be for custom tailoring the environment. I would just like a lightweight image my app can use to run on the Spark cluster. Not sure how to tie it all together.

So I see 2 options from the documentation

1. Use [this docker file](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/resource-managers/kubernetes/docker/src/main/dockerfiles/spark/Dockerfile) as a base image.
2. use the `docker-image-tool.sh` script.

But I'm not sure which option I need to go for or when to use either option? Why use one over the other? Is there another option? Is there a prebuilt image that I can just copy my application into and use that to run?

Answer (score 3):

Spark's `docker-image-tool.sh` is a tool script to create Spark's image. If you want a lightweight docker image, you can just tweak the Dockerfile that comes with the project or write your own - don't forget to edit the `entrypoint.sh` script as well.

Generally the steps for getting your Spark App to Kubernetes goes like this:

1. Create a base spark image for you to use.
2. Push it to a docker registry - if you are using minikube, the  you can use the `-m` flag to move it to the minikube env.
3. Write a Spark Application, Package it and then run the `spark-submit` command.

Note:
If you are not invested so much in Kubernetes and just want to quickly try this whole platform out, you can just proxy the `kube-api-server` by running the following command:

```
kubectl proxy
```

It would start serving the api server on `localhost:8001`, then you can submit your spark app by running a command like

```
bin/spark-submit \
--master k8s://http:localhost:8001 \ #If you don't specify the protocol here, it'd default to https
--deploy-mode client \ #if you want to go for `cluster mode` then you'd have to set up a service account
--name sparkle \
--class edu.girdharshubham \ 
--conf spark.executor.instances=1 \ #Number of pods
--conf spark.kubernetes.container.image=<your-spark-image>
--conf spark.kubernetes.driver.pod.name="sparkle"
--conf spark.kubernetes.hadoop.configMapName="HADOOP_CONF_DIR"
--conf spark.kubernetes.executor.deleteOnTermination
path/to/jar
```

Consideration for running in client mode:

- Make sure that the node - VM - you are running the aforementioned command from is network addressable from the pods
- executor(pod) will run a JAVA process
- The default Dockerfile uses tini -  tiny but valid `init` for containers.
- `spark.kubernetes.executor.deleteOnTermination` - This conf should be your go to conf if you are just starting out, by default pods are deleted in case of failure or normal termination. This would help you debug rather quickly about what's going on with your executor pods - whether they are failing or not.

Comment: Great call out on the `deleteOnTermination` flag that's quite helpful.

Comment: Separate question - does the docker image that you package your app in have to contain the entire spark distribution? It looks like even in the `docker-image-tool.sh` some unnecessary things are packaged like examples. I would think there could be just some client library you could package in the docker image not the entire spark library.

Comment: I added an additional question on using the base dockerfile vs the `docker-image-tool.sh` script - if you have any insight on that question please share! Thanks

Comment: Hi - when you say "don't forget to edit the `entrypoint.sh` script as well." - what did you mean? What do we need to edit in that file?

Answer (score 0):

I think I confused you a little bit. Readying a spark distribution's image and packaging your app are two separate things. Here's how you'd deploy your app using Kuberentes as a scheduler.

Step 1: Build Spark's image

```
./bin/docker-image-tool.sh -r asia.gcr.io/menace -t v3.0.0 build
```

Step 2: Push the image to your Docker registry

```
./bin/docker-image-tool.sh -r asia.gcr.io/menace -t v3.0.0 push
```

Step 3: Configure your Kubernetes to be able to pull your image, In most cases, it just requires setting up `imagePullSecrets`.

[Pull Images from a private registry](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/)

Step 4: Write your spark app

```
package edu.girdharshubham

import scala.math.random

import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession


object Solution {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val spark = SparkSession
      .builder
      .master("k8s://http://localhost:8001")
      .config("spark.submit.deployMode","client")
      .config("spark.executor.instances", "2")
      .config("spark.kubernetes.container.image", "asia.gcr.io/menace/spark:v3.0.0")
      .appName("sparkle")
      .getOrCreate()

    import spark.implicits._
    val someDF = Seq(
      (8, "bat"),
      (64, "mouse"),
      (-27, "horse")
    ).toDF("number", "word")


    println("========================================================")
    println(someDF.take(1).foreach(println))
    println("========================================================")

    spark.stop()
  }
}
```

Step 4: Run your application

```
sbt run
```

This would result in executor pods being spawned on your cluster.

Step 5: Package your application

```
sbt package
```

Step 6: Use the spark submit command to run your app - Refer my initial answer

Now coming on to your question on packaging Spark's distribution, be careful about the version that you package and the dependencies that you use. Spark is a little iffy about versions.

Comment: So my question is about packaging my application, not the spark distribution. I installed Spark from spark-operator and need my application to be a docker image

Comment: Oh! In that case, you need to provide just the following in your manifest. The base image will be your spark distribution.
```
  mainApplicationFile: local:///opt/spark/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.12-2.3.0.jar
  mainClass: org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi ```
Or if you are just testing it out atm, you can package your application along with. Place your code in the spark dir and change the Dockerfile to also COPY that application in the spark image

Comment: Ok I think I understand. So I still need to build an image with all of spark dependencies in it? Would I need to change `docker-image-tool.sh` script to COPY my new code into it? Or change one of the docker files?

Comment: Yes, you'd still need to build the spark base image - unless you plan on using a community provided image. add a COPY directive in the original dockerfile at  kubernetes/dockerfiles/spark/Dockerfile. After that run the docker image tool with a build flag and then with a push flag